# jQuery Calculation issue

Tags: jquery

Having a small issue with the following bit of jQuery. It's used to calculate line items and aggregate totals.

e.g.

```
line_item 1: qty x rate + vat (if vatable) = subtotal
    
line_item 1: qty x rate + vat (if vatable) = subtotal
    
subtotal: sum(qtys x rates)
vat: sum (subtotal x vat formula)
total : sum(subtotals)
```

Heres the code, any help will be much appreciated;

```
function vatable(checkbox) {
    if(checkbox.attr('checked')) {
        return 14/100;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

function recalc(){
    jQuery("input[class^=ltotal]").calc(
        "qty * rate + (((qty * rate) * vat))",
        {
            qty: jQuery("input[class^=lqty]"),
            rate: jQuery("input[class^=lrate]"),
            vat : vatable(jQuery("input.lvat"))
        },
        function (s){
            return s.toFixed(2);
        },
        function ($this){
            var sum = $this.sum();
            if(jQuery("input[class^=lvat]").attr('checked')) {
                jQuery("input[class=subtotal]").calc( ((sum/114)*100).toFixed(2));
                jQuery("input[class=vat]").calc(((sum/114)*14).toFixed(2));
                jQuery("input[class=total]").calc((sum).toFixed(2));
            } else {
                jQuery("input[class=subtotal]").calc( sum.toFixed(2) );
                jQuery("input[class=vat]").calc(0);
                jQuery("input[class=total]").calc( sum.toFixed(2) );
            }
        }
    );
}

$(document).ready( function () {
    $('input[class^=lqty]').bind('keyup', recalc);
    $('input[class^=lvat]').click(recalc);
    $('input[class^=lrate]').bind('keyup', recalc);
    recalc();
});
```

The issue is that the checkbox input.lvat is used to set whether the line total is vatable and if so add the result of the vat formula to the line items total. The checkbox is only being picked up on the first line item and not on the consecutive line items and therefore has no effect on the line items total. VAT needs to be added per line item. So im a little stuck as to why the consecutive checkboxes are not being picked up. Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: What is your problem? What goes wrong?

Comment: Appologies didnt realise my question got cut short.

The issue is that the checkbox input.lvat is used to set whether the line total is vatable and if so add the result of the vat formula to the line items total. 

The checkbox is only being picked up on the first line item and not on the consecutive line items and therefore has no  effect on the line items total. VAT needs to be added per line item. So im a little stuck as to why the consecutive checkboxes are not being picked up.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Some html or a link to the page might help

Comment: Please read this, revise your question accordingly and add the code using the snippet functionality. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example